# c# asp.net mvc - simplification

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, boolean

how can I simplify this composite condition?

```
    @if (Model.State.Inventory[0] == true
     && Model.State.Inventory[1] == true
     && Model.State.Inventory[2] == true
     && Model.State.Inventory[3] == true
     && Model.State.Inventory[4] == true
     && Model.State.Inventory[5] == true)
    {
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" asp-page="Cellar">Go to the Cellar</a>
    }
```

Comment: `if(Model.State.Inventory.Take(6).All(x => x == true))`.  Or with C#8: `if(Model.State.Inventory[..^5].All(x => x == true))`

Comment: Are there always six inventory items?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using LINQ's [Take()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-5.0) and [All()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0):

```
@if (Model.State.Inventory.Take(6).All(x => x == true))
{
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" asp-page="Cellar">Go to the Cellar</a>
}
```

Or if you are using C#8 you can use [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) with LINQ:

```
@if (Model.State.Inventory.Inventory[..6].All(x => x == true))
{
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" asp-page="Cellar">Go to the Cellar</a>
}
```

Comment: [..5] not [..^5]